# Register Data-Tier Application - "Database source is not a supported version of SQL Server" error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools

I have a SQL Server Express 2014 database.  In SSMS, whenever I attempt to register the database as a data-tier application, I receive the error "Database source is not a supported version of SQL Server (localdb)\ProjectsV12 (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac)".  How do I resolve?

**TMI:**

I have a SSDT project where I am attempting to write conditional scripts based on database version.  So for instance, a lookup script might look like:

```
DECLARE @version_source AS VARCHAR(100) = (SELECT type_version FROM msdb.dbo.sysdac_instances WHERE database_name = DB_NAME());

IF @version_source IS NULL
BEGIN
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT instructor_title ON;

    INSERT INTO instructor_title (id, name, description) VALUES
        (1, 'Instructor', NULL),
        (2, 'Assistant Professor', NULL),
        (3, 'Associate Professor', NULL),
        (4, 'Professor', NULL)
    ;

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT instructor_title OFF;
END
```

When I publish, I check "Register as a Data-tier Application" and everything works fine.  When I start debugging (which deploys to (localdb)\ProjectsV12), my logic fails.  The SQL Server express database won't register as a data-tier application.  This results in the variable @version_source always returning NULL, so my script condition always is true.  I realize I could write an idempotent or database state conditional script instead, but feel strongly a database version conditional script is the best architecture decision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try checking the box for "Allow incompatible platform" which you can find by clicking on the "Advanced..." button on the "Debug" tab of "Project Properties".

The other thing is: what is your target platform? The drop-down list in the "Project Settings" tab of "Project Properties"? It should be set to SQL Server 2014. If SQL Server 2014 is not an option you should get the latest version of SSDT (though be sure to create a system restore point before installing as for some reason the latest version (as of a few months ago) trashed my Visual Studio, wouldn't compile stuff, and wouldn't uninstall easily; and the only tips on S.O. or anywhere else were for VS 2013 and I have 2012).

Comment: Thanks, I was using SSMS 2012 instead of 2014.